# Restore deleted Mac user to another Mac

Tags: macos, user-accounts, user-management, macos-highsierra

When I delete a user in Mac OS Sierra, I get the option to 'Save the home folder in a disk image'.  Is that image portable to other Macs?  Is there a restore function to create the user again on this Mac?  Would the restore function work on another Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be your answer or atleast some help?

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25515?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

And if you want to move the user to the other Mac you should copy the users disk image into a USB drive and by that way copy it to the other Mac.

-Flamma